# Multiply all numbers in a range of numbers

Tags: python, multiplication

I am trying to write a function to multiply all the numbers between (let's say 1 and 4) the result should be 1 * 2 * 3 = 6. However, I am having some trouble writing this piece of code. I have posted below what I have tried.

```
import numpy as np
def multiply_between(num1, num2):
    result = np.prod(range(num1, num2))
    return result
```

The other way I am thinking is a little like this but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
def multiply_between(num1, num2):

    for num in range(num1, num2):
        return num * num
```

I get the right answer when I use numpy, but I would like to know if there is an algorithmic way to do it.

Comment: Note that `return` causes the function to exit. You don't want to call it in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the running product, then return it at the very end:

```
def multiply_between(num1, num2):
    result = 1
    for num in range(num1, num2):
        result *= num
    return result
```

If you want a one-liner, use `functools.reduce` with `operator.mul`:

```
import functools
import operator

def multiply_between(num1, num2):
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, range(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Ah yeah, that's a little more elegant than mine :\

Comment: I might even initialize result to num1 and start the range at num1 + 1

Comment: The current definition allows for empty products like `multiply_between(3,3)`.

Comment: @chepner That's good to note, though I don't know what OP would want in these situations. They can add conditionals to check for empty ranges if needed.

Comment: The mathematical definition of an empty product is 1.

Comment: @chepner Ah, I see what you were getting at. Yes, that would make initializing `result` to `num1` a little less correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the result of the previous multiplications before you return:

```
def multiply_between(num1, num2):
    total = None
    for num in range(num1, num2):
        if total is None:
            total = num
        else:
            total *= num
    return total
```